# Trying to read a local text file into an array (javascript/jquery) to be read from Androids WebView

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, android-webview

I am trying to read a local text file into an array using Javascript or jQuery. In the end this will be implemented in an Android application using Android's WebView. Here is what I have at the moment.

```
var cardRules = new Array;
$.get('UserFile.txt', function(data){
        cardRules = data.split('\n');
        console.log(cardRules);
    });
```

However Chrome flashes up this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Sam/Documents/RingOfFire/UserFile.txt. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720201/load-textfile-in-webview-android

Comment: Thats not want I want to do. I have a HTML file thats being loaded through the WebView, and then Im using JS/Jqeury to read a file needed for the HTML. If that makes any sense!